# Building navmesh asynchronously during runtime in unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, navmesh

I faced the problem that the scene of my game changes depending on the actions of the player (he can put obstacles) and navmesh agent should take into account these changes and destroy them.

So I need to recalculate paths for navmesh agent right in the time of the game, I found the function navMeshSurface.BuildNavMeshAsync(); in the hope that I can bake and the game would not stop. When this method is called the game freezes.

What could be the problem with asynchrony?

Perhaps there is an alternative to rebaking, please give me ideas

Last iteration

```
private async void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N))
        {
            SpawnNextAtRandomSpawner();
            navMeshSurface = GameObject.Find("Navmesh").GetComponent<NavMeshSurface>();
            await UpdateNavMeshAsync();
        }
    }

    async Task UpdateNavMeshAsync()
    {
        navMeshSurface.RemoveData();
        navMeshSurface.BuildNavMeshAsync(); //Freeze moment
    }
```

Comment: Don't make `Update` await your call .. of course this freezes as a **frame** in Unity is defined by all `Update` (among other things) running once ... simply do not await your call at all but make it run asynchronous

Comment: Why not have navmesh modifiers on the places objects that mean its auto cut out. Then no need to recalculate

Comment: Something being "async" makes no guarantee to what degree it is async. It can have a fairly slow synchronous part, or it can just lie about being asynchronous. You need to check the documentation. I have not used Unity, but is there no feature to handle temporary blocking objects? Rebuilding navmeshes from scratch seem like an extremely heavy weight solution.

Comment: Where did you find this method? https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ai.navigation@2.0/api/Unity.AI.Navigation.NavMeshSurface.html#methods

Comment: @JonasH yes, depen ding on old or new version theres components to add so you can tell navmesh to include or exclude and it auto calculates..

Comment: @BugFinder i have navmesh modifier component on my placeable objects prefabs, but after being placed/destroyed i have to rebuild nav mesh for these changes to be considered for path finding of agents. Maybe you are talking about something else? I'm quite new to  navmesh, so details would be appreciated. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over thinking it way too much

so this link takes you to a video of the below in action.

https://imgur.com/a/FO1cpV8

```
public class spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
public int Delay = 5;
public GameObject cube;
public NavMeshSurface surface;
    private float nextspawntime = 0;

    Vector3 newpos()
    {
        return new Vector3(Random.Range(-24,24),0,Random.Range(-24,24));
    }
    void Update()
    {
        nextspawntime += Time.deltaTime; 
        if (nextspawntime> Delay)
        {
            nextspawntime = 0;
            Instantiate(cube, newpos(), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: navmeshobject]

Comment: Never heard of that component in context of 2d project, but it works just fine.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: navmesh is not specific to 2d, it is 3d too